# How to cascade delete from another table, when foreign key is on the other table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

There are 2 tables:
users: [user_id, user_name]
users_toys: [toy_id, user_id]
A user can have multiple toys.

If I delete a user, I would like all users_toys to be deleted.
But The foreign keys are in users_toys, and not in users table. So how do I tell MySQL on delete cascade if the key is in the other table?

Comment: Why don't you try and share what happens?

Comment: see witch foreign key constraint is in user_toys and Drop ut and finally add a new one with ON DELETE CASCADE plus what the old key had

Comment: If you have a foreign key set up in users_toys with on delete cascade then when you delete users users_toys will delete. I am not clear from the question whether you haven't understood this or that you have fks but they are not set to on delete cascade. Please add your table definitions.